# Enable USB Debugging and remote control (scrcpy) with broken screen

Tags: adb

and happy holidays. Apologies if this question is more appropriate for SuperUser, I ask here in case there is a programmatic solution to my problem.

In summary: On an Android device with a broken screen, assuming that USB Debugging is enabled or that the connected device is not trusted, is there any way to perform remote control?

So I have a Pixel 3a which I used to control just fine via scrcpy 1.21. Today the screen broke to the point that I only see a few glitchy lines, even though it looks like I can theoretically control it (based on the sounds, I managed to enter the log-in pattern).

The problem is that `adb devices` does not recognize it, even though the system (Ubuntu or Windows) recognizes that a Pixel 3a was connected for charging.

Is there any way I can salvage this situation?

ADB commands failed. scrcpy failed.

Comment: Android user questions are off-topic on Stackoverflow as well as Superuser. They are on-topic on https://android.stackexchange.com. scrcpy requires enabled and working adb, so this won't work. Connect USB mouse or keyboard for device interaction (if the Android device supported USB OTG).